# What do you call a number with no repeating digits?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

A word with no repeated characters is called an isogram.

Is there a word for a number with no repeating digits?

For example: 123 is a ____.

To clarify further, for a decimal number system the number could never be longer than 10 digits and for any other base number system the number could never be longer than the total number of distinct symbols in that number system.

Comment: Can your number be longer than 10 digits?

Comment: Couldn't it be longer than 10 digits in hexadecimal?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a name for this category.  I would say "numbers with no repeating digits."  I also am seeing "isogram numbers," but I don't think that's a term.

Comment: A sequence (of length r) of non-repeating elements is called a 'permutation' (or r-permutation) in math, but one wouldn't call a number like that, whose representation in some base has no repeated digits, a permutation.

Comment: Are you sure "isogram" cannot be used for this?

Comment: Interestingly, the OED doesn't have this definition for *isogram*, only a definition relating to diagrams with some equality of feature. Presumably when the entry is updated this new coinage will be reflected. If you wanted to form your own word, since *isogram* comes from Greek *ἴσος* ("equal") + *γράμμα* ("letter") I think ***isarithm*** seems likely, substituting *αριθμός* ("number") for the second part. (Of course, based on the etymology of the word, I would have thought that *toot* and *mama* would also qualify as isograms, having an equal number of each letter.)

Comment: Actually, I think what you are after is the term "distinct digits."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I'm actually after is a word to describe the term "distinct digits".

Comment: @1006a 'If you wanted to form your own word' belongs on the 'fiction' sites, not on English Language and (present accepted) Usage. 'Word' means more than 'string of umpteen letters, surrounded by white spaces, pronounceable and perhaps showing connection with Latin etc roots'.

Comment: @1006a: I don’t mind making up words where no existing word can be attested. But wouldn’t ***isopsifi*** be preferable? The *digit* / *figure* versus *number* distinction also exists in Greek: *ψηφίο* versus *αριθμός*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set of all numbers with no repeating digits is [sequence A010784](http://oeis.org/A010784) in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. On OEIS, such a number is called a **xenodrome**.

This word is made of the prefix *xeno-*, meaning "alien," with the root *drome*, meaning "running, course, race track." It was probably coined by analogy with "palindrome" (with the etymological meaning "running back"), and I suppose the notion is that as you run from one end of the number to the other, every digit you encounter is an alien.

However, this word seems to be extremely rare; it was probably coined by OEIS contributors and it hasn't spread far from there. The only other usage of this word I was able to find in a Google search was the Stack Exchange post "[All the Xenodromes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101188/11067)," which almost certainly got the word directly from OEIS.

Comment: Please add substantiating references from reputable sources.

Comment: @Edwin For the word itself, OEIS seems to be the most reputable source which has ever used it. Should I add references for the meanings of "xeno-" and "drome" as well?

Comment: The OEIS is a reputable source.

Comment: @Lambie It may be for subject-specific issues, but ELU looks at standard English usage. Is 'xenodrome' in a reputable dictionary? We used '1010 acid', a well-known label, when I was working in a research lab, but it's hardly a term that is suitable to suggest as a 'word' on a site for people looking at non-niche English. MathematicsSE, maybe.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not my circus, not my monkeys.  But, it hardly seems that *common* usage is the standard for this site.  Otherwise, we'd be called English Language and Common Usage StackExchange.  I will grant that there doesn't seem to be a better source than OEIS, but if this an accepted technical term, it is just that.  Accepted.

Comment: @David M If we have to use sources such as OEIS, surely we're off-topic. How many English language students is this going to benefit? Do they cite CGEL over on Maths?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Then vote to close the question as off topic, not harangue someone who found a reputable answer to the question.  I'd even join you if I had any close votes left.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single word, but the very unsatifactory answer is *isogram number*.  You can find it in these less-than-reputable sources.

http://mentalfloss.com/article/535184/isogram-numbers 
https://www.sporcle.com/games/ShepherdBook/Isogram_Numbers

Comment: That could work, but I'm not sure about the applicability of this description, which appears similarly in both links: "Can you name the only whole numbers with **no repeating letters** in their name?" It seems to refer to spelling numbers. Would inverting it ("numeral isogram," with numeral as an adjective describing that the characters to be counted are digits and not letters) work better?

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you are referring to?

> ### [*repetend*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/repetend) [ rep-i-tend, rep-i-tend ] / ˈrɛp ɪˌtɛnd, ˌrɛp ɪˈtɛnd /
>
> **noun**
>
> 1. *Mathematics*. the part of a repeating decimal that is repeated, as 1234 in 0.123412341234. …
> 2. *Music*. a phrase or sound that is repeated.
> 3. *Prosody*. a word, phrase, line, or longer element that is repeated, sometimes with variation, at irregular intervals in a poem.
>
> > — [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/repetend)

or:

> ### [Full Repetend Prime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FullReptendPrime.html)
>
> A prime  for which ¹⁄ has a maximal period decimal expansion of *p − 1* digits. Full reptend primes are sometimes also called long primes (Conway and Guy 1996, pp. 157–163 and 166–171). There is a surprising connection between full reptend primes and Fermat primes.
>
> > — [Wolfram Math Word](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FullReptendPrime.html)